# VB.NET SQL Query Null value

Tags: sql, vb.net, null

So my query is this

```
SELECT pm,SiteNumber,Client,OnHold,Urgent,SARequired,MissingInformation FROM Sites WHERE OnHold<>'' or Urgent<>'' or MissingInformation<>'' or SARequired<>'' and PM='K' and PM is not null and (ProjectStatus<>'Complete' or ProjectStatus<>'Archived') Order By SiteNumber asc
```

where PM is not Null - I have also tried in vb.net to set the value to

```
PM<>dbnull.value 
'also tried 
PM<> is null 
'or just 
PM<> Null
```

None of them seem to leave out the nulls

also confusing me that I'm asking to only see PM where PM='K' as in the query above but I see 'R'

Here is what I'm getting back

```
pm
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
R
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Yes on purpose I tested 'K' for the PM Column since I know I don't have any

I'm sure its something stupid simple , just can't put my finger on it

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have 'pm' at the beginning of your `SELECT` and then later use 'PM'.  That can make a difference.  `SELECT **PM**, SiteNumber, Client, OnHold, Urgent, SARequired, MissingInformation FROM Sites WHERE OnHold<>'' or Urgent<>'' or MissingInformation<>'' or SARequired<>'' and PM='K' and PM is not null and (ProjectStatus<>'Complete' or ProjectStatus<>'Archived') Order By SiteNumber asc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `IS NOT NULL`. But the problem in your query are the `OR`s.

formatted:

```
SELECT columns
FROM   sites 
WHERE  onhold <> '' 
        OR urgent <> '' 
        OR missinginformation <> '' 
        OR sarequired <> '' 
           AND pm = 'K' 
           AND pm IS NOT NULL 
           AND ( projectstatus <> 'Complete' 
                  OR projectstatus <> 'Archived' ) 
ORDER  BY sitenumber ASC
```

If you want to exclude `NULLS` in any case put the rest of the conditions in parentheses:

```
SELECT columns 
FROM   sites 
WHERE  pm IS NOT NULL 
       AND ( onhold <> '' 
              OR urgent <> '' 
              OR missinginformation <> '' 
              OR sarequired <> '' 
                 AND pm = 'K' 
                 AND ( projectstatus <> 'Complete' 
                        OR projectstatus <> 'Archived' ) ) 
ORDER  BY sitenumber ASC
```

**Edit**: *how can we fix the R showing up instead of K when i tell it to look for K not R*

I must have overlooked that question. When you only want to have rows with `pm = 'K'` you don't need to ask for non-null rows at all because `pm = 'K'` is not-null implicitly:

```
WHERE  pm = 'K' 
           AND ( onhold <> ''  ...
```

Comment: Wow thats absolutely solving the Null issue thanks!
 - Now how can we fix the R showing up instead of K when i tell it to look for K not R.?

EDIT: i had to switch one of the brackets around to get the and seperated from the or's - THANKS will mark correct as soon as it lets me ( 5 min or so )

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses around the initial `or` conditions in the `where` clause.

```
SELECT pm,SiteNumber,Client,OnHold,Urgent,SARequired,MissingInformation
FROM Sites
WHERE (OnHold<>'' or Urgent<>'' or MissingInformation<>'' or SARequired<>'') and
      PM='K' and PM is not null and (ProjectStatus<>'Complete' or ProjectStatus<>'Archived')
Order By SiteNumber asc
```

In SQL, `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.  So, the original statement was parsing as:

```
SELECT pm,SiteNumber,Client,OnHold,Urgent,SARequired,MissingInformation
FROM Sites
WHERE OnHold<>'' or Urgent<>'' or MissingInformation<>'' or 
      (SARequired<>'' and PM='K' and PM is not null and (ProjectStatus<>'Complete' or ProjectStatus<>'Archived'))
Order By SiteNumber asc
```